# Planetes, episode 10 and the message inside the compass

Tags: planetes

In Planetes ep. 10 everything deals with the story of one of the main characters.

Yuri, who had lost his wife during a suborbital flight, is since then on a constant search for the wherabouts of her lost remains. The compass is depicted in the opening credits shortly before the accident where she was lost.

When Yuri finally finds the compass of his wife during ep.10 a sketchy writing inside the compass' lid becomes visible. "please save yuri"

Since this show was rather popular and this episode was considered one of the best a lot of people have thought about the true meaning of "please save yuri".

E.g.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/45gxtw/spoilers_planetes_rewatch_discussion_thread/
- https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/Planetes
- https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=40540

However all discussions or analyses I found either consider this a kind of a general charm or caused by some premonition Yuri's wife might have encountered before the flight. In this context it is also asked why she wrote it in English while it wasn't the mother's tongue of either and they had other means to communicate. An explanation for choosing English is difficult based on these assumptions.

But to me it is obvious, that she had carved the words into the metal during the few minutes after the accident she had before dying from asphyxiation. In this context it makes sense to me that she wrote in English as this wasn't a charm but more a serious plea to whomever might find that compass. This also should explain why the words were carved into the lid so sketchy.

Whenever I find myself proposing an explanation nobody else has brought up before, I'm starting to think, I'm wrong. So I want to hear more suggestions about the possible intent of the makers of the series.

side note: If I'm right, I think this episode much more heart wrenching than with all other given explanations.